# java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Error while Installing APK

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to install my project on my device but I am getting the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KhqU.png)

This is the error:

`java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Error while Installing APK`

Please help me with this and also could anyone tell me about R in java file

Comment: In android studio goto File Menu Chose invalidate restart/caches option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 run->cmd->your_android_sdk_path->platform-tools>
Then write the below commands.

adb kill-server - To kill the server forcefully

adb start-server - To start the server

UPDATED:

F:\android-sdk-windows latest\platform-tools>adb kill-server

F:\android-sdk-windows latest\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Comment: In android studio goto File Menu Chose invalidate restart/caches option

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. Could you please tell me why this happened?

And what should I do if it happens again?

Thanks again.

Comment: Some caches stored in automatic file generation. It may not refresh all the times. so only

Answer (score 0):

If its a real device, In my case disabling and enabling the **usb debugging** option worked. 
Killing and Starting the adb server didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was to disabling and enabling USB debugging but with also **revoking** computer autorisations and then re-enabling. I hope it helps someone since I struggled a lot.